# clang-tidy bugprone-unused-return-value: how to check all functions?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I have clang-tidy checking for unused return values with `bugprone-unused-return-value` check. Unfortunately it only checks return values from list of functions specified with `CheckedFunctions` parameter. I would like to check usage of return value from all functions, but am not able to figure out what to write to `CheckedFunctions` to do this.

What should I write to `bugprone-unused-return-value`'s parameter `CheckedFunctions` for it to check all functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `bugprone-unused-return-value` check is not built to check all functions.

You can either specify `CheckedFunctions` or if you omit the specification then a default list of functions will be used. There is no possibility of using wildcards or regular expressions here.

See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-unused-return-value.html). I also checked the [source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/bugprone/UnusedReturnValueCheck.cpp) of the check just to be sure but in current version of clang-tidy (14) this can't be done.